# Change font color when posting new iCal events

Tags: calendar, font

I have an iMac with OS X version 10.9.4. When using the iCal application I cannot change the color of a new event I post to match the color I've  chosen for the event.  Example: If I post a Red color coded event the lettering for my description is black.  I want the description I type for my Red event to be Red, not Black.  It would stand out as what color code the event is. Currently if I post a new Calendar event and choose a color for it just a small dot appears next to black font description of my event.  I want colored font to match the colored dot on my calendar.  Additionally there is a Gray Birthday event option but I cannot place any personalized  Gray color coded birthday events. I want the typing font color to match the event color for new iCal events I add and I want to be able to post Birthdays using the Gray color set up on my iCal menu.

Comment: Could you edit if you are using iCal on Mac or the web or iOS? Adding versions for the software helps us help you.

Answer (score 2):

1. The calendar app doesn't give you that level of flexibility. Apple has designed it to look a certain way, and that's the way it's going to look, bar some pretty serious hacking. [Busycal](http://www.busymac.com/busycal/) is a calendar app that does use the calendar's color for the text, not just for the dot.
2. The "Birthdays" calendar is a special one automatically generated based on the birthday info you enter for your contacts. You can't edit it directly.